# Selenium WebDriver Java - click a button inside of a table with no id

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to `click` a `button` that is located within a table.

I've tried searching by `linkText`, and `xPath` without success.

The code I've tried is:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ddial_o']")));
WebElement table = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='ddial_b']"));
table.findElement(By.xpath("//tbody/tr/td/a[contains(text(), 'OK')]")).click();
```

I used list to try to ensure that the element was actually found, and though the list.size() displays as 2 and 1 for my commands, I can't seem to find the element.

Here is the `HTML` Code of the page, I keep getting a `NoSuchElementException`

```
<div style="z-index: 1004; width: 400px; left: 596px; top: 70px;" class="ddial_o">
    <div class="ddial_o2">
        <div class="ddial_i"><a style="outline: medium none;" class="d2l-offscreen" href="javascript://">Jump to bottom of Confirmation dialog</a>
            <div class="ddial_t d2l-dragdrop-draggable">
                <table width="100%">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td></td>
                            <td class="ddial_h"><a style="outline: medium none;" tabindex="-1"><h1>Confirmation</h1></a>
                            </td>
                            <td class="ddial_close"><a title="Close this Dialog" style="display: none;" href="javascript://"><span><span class="d2l-offscreen">Close this Dialog</span></span></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <table width="100%">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 1%;" valign="top"><img style="width: 48px; height: 48px; padding: 7px 0px 7px 7px;" src="/d2l/img/lp/dialog/confirm.gif">
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <div style="overflow: auto; margin: 10px;" class="ddial_c">
                                <div>
                                    <p style="margin-top: 0px; font-weight: bold; display: block;">The quiz you are about to begin may take a few minutes to load.
                                        <br>
                                        <br>
                                    </p>
                                    <p style="margin-bottom: 0px; display: block;">The timer will not begin until after the set up process is finished.
                                        <br>
                                        <br>You can submit your quiz responses past the time period allocated for taking this quiz, but doing so will result in a score of zero being assigned.Click OK to start your quiz or click Cancel if you do not wish to start it now.</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <table style="display: block;" class="ddial_b">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><a aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" role="button" class="vui-button d2l-button vui-button-primary">OK</a><a aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" role="button" class="vui-button d2l-button">Cancel</a>
                        </td>
                        <td align="center" width="100%"></td>
                        <td align="right"></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <a style="outline: medium none;" title=" " tabindex="-1"> </a><a style="outline: medium none;" class="d2l-offscreen" href="javascript://">Jump to top of Confirmation dialog</a>
        </div>
        <div class="ddial_f"><span aria-live="assertive"></span>
            <div title="Resize this Dialog" class="ddial_fr"></div>
            <div class="clear d2l-clear"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like it is in an alert window, have you tried to find this alert window first?

Comment: for your second attempt, you do not have to use FindElementsBy, as there is only one button to be found. Use FindElementBy instead.

Comment: I've tried to find an alert and i got the NoAlertPresentException, do you have any other idea for how to proceed?

Comment: try looking for a "iframe"

Comment: There is no iframe. It's especially strange because I successfully automated another pop up that is html coded exactly like this one using linkText.

Comment: did you receive any exception?

Comment: I receive a element not found exception every time. I'm trying to xpath to it but I'm having trouble navigating through the table.

Comment: If you actually want a solution, you need to share HTML instead of screenshot...

Comment: And could you tell me when this popup occurs... I mean   it occurs when you are doing some action on page or anything else...describe it also...

Comment: It occurs after I click another button that says "Start quiz". I'm sorry I am very new to this site, how do I share HTML?

Comment: The best/easiest way to put HTML into your question is to paste it into an HTML beautifier like http://www.cleancss.com/html-beautify/, format it, and then with all lines selected press TAB twice to indent all lines with 4 spaces. (NOTE: Four spaces before a line formats it as code on this site.) Copy the text and paste it into your answer. Done.

Comment: Thanks, I've posted the HTML of the page along with a new attempt I've tried. I still receive a NoSuchElement Exception. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: @Kevin why are you going to switch to frame while in your posted HTML I couldn't see any frame... which class you are providing to switching frame it's see as div's class..Are you sure there is a frame exist?? If yes share it also...

Comment: @Kevin just remove `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ddial_o']")));` line of code... and it would work..:)